# Coreboot + QEMU Tutorial Request (Google has failed)

Tags: kernel, boot, virtual-machine, bios, qemu

Can anyone point me in the direction of an end-to-end idiot-proof coreboot+qemu tutorial?

I'm having trouble understanding how qemu is set up to emulate different hardware (also having trouble getting my head around the chicken and egg status of kernel cross-compilation)

[These tutorials](http://www.coreboot.org/QEMU#Tutorials) have several gaps that are catching me unawares. I'm not usually an embedded guy, and my virtualisation background is more enterprise level than hardware level.

Answer (score 2):

Stop in the #coreboot on IRC or join the email list and point out where you are having a problem. We try to make the documentation clear, but both coreboot and qemu are developing rapidly.